# Dynamically name a function as the script, Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to dynamically name a function in a script as the name of the script? For example, if the script is called `foo.py`, is it possible to dynamically name a function in `foo.py` as `foo`? The reason I'm asking is that I import functions from several scripts and the naming convention is `function_to_import = script` - and to avoid any misspelling in the functions I'd like it to be dynamic. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry didn't clearly understand the question, do you mean you want to dynamically change the function name?

Comment: Yes, if the name of the script is `foo.py`, can I set the name of a function in `foo.py` to `foo` without doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to assign a new name to a function, please note this would not change the name of the function, but the `new name` would also be pointing to that function.

Example 1 - While importing you can use `as` keyword to assign a new name, and then use it in the script using the new name

```
from foo import func as foo
foo()
```

Example 2 - You can assign the function to a new variable (a new name) and then use the new name to call it -

```
>>> def func(a):
...     print("Hello")
...
>>> foo = func
>>> foo(1)
Hello
```

There may be more ways to do this.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, simple and elegant solution. Thanks! Will mark it as answered, but have to wait for 6 minutes...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do something like

```
def main():
    pass

globals()[__name__] = main

# if you no longer want the function to exist under its original name
del main
```

Messing with `globals()` is not generally recommended. I think it would make for clearer code to just bite the bullet and manually type out the name you need, but this is probably not the worst thing to do.

Note that this only changes the name that the function can be accessed with. It doesn't change the name of the underlying function object that you're accessing. If your code relies on that name, then you will have to do something more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I went with Anand's answer though as it was simple enough and solved the problem

Comment: Yeah, in my opinion that's a better way to do it anyway. (Though it does suggest that the question you asked is not quite the one you needed answered ;-)

Comment: Haha, no, not really. What you and ssundarraj proposed was how I wanted to do in the first place - but Anand's was simpler, so I had complicated things...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__file__` to get the filename and then assign the function to that file.

```
def my_function():
    print "Hello, World!"

exec(__file__.split('.')[0] + " = my_function")
```

If you add this to your file, it will dynamically name the function `my_function` as the name of your file.

Comment: Thanks for this! This is actually what I was aiming for in the beginning, but Anand's answer was rather easy to implement by just naming the "main" function in each script as `main` and then `from func import main as func`.

Comment: His solution would be better. Anyway, glad to be of help!